How can I retrieve source code of given contract address but Etherscan doesn't have any
screenshot of Etherscan
I want to deploy UniswapV2Factory on local network and i find it need an address
constructor(address _feeToSetter) public {
    feeToSetter = _feeToSetter;
}

then I search this address on Etherscan but no source code found.
does anyone know how to resolve it

In your case you need to provided an address to the constructor, so you will be able to change the reciever of the fee and an address that can change the fee reciever in the future:
    function setFeeTo(address _feeTo) external {
        require(msg.sender == feeToSetter, 'UniswapV2: FORBIDDEN');
        feeTo = _feeTo;
    }

    function setFeeToSetter(address _feeToSetter) external {
        require(msg.sender == feeToSetter, 'UniswapV2: FORBIDDEN');
        feeToSetter = _feeToSetter;
    }

